# mysql How To join 2 column value into 2 column value

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables with columns as follows:

1. khs (id, year, program, codemk)
2. subjects (id, year, program, codemk,namemk, tm, pr, lp)

I want to have a result containing:

```
codemk, namemk, tm, pr, lp
```

**Note:** Fields `year`, `program` and `codemk` in `khs` table each is not unique also in `subjects` table. But combine the 3 value of those fields make a unique value.

I tried this:

```
SELECT khs.id khs.codemk, subjects.namemk, subjects.tm, subject.pr, subjects.lp
FROM khs 
RIGHT JOIN subjects
ON khs.year + khs.program +khs.codemk = subjects.year + subjects.program + subjects.codemk;
```

but the result for `tm`, `pr` and `lp` is not what I expected. What am I missing? Sorry I am new to MySQL and how do i create it to new table view.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add some examples of the output? I don't understand you

Comment: Do you wanna compare the join concating values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT khs.id khs.codemk, subjects.namemk, subjects.tm, subject.pr, subjects.lp
FROM khs 
RIGHT JOIN subjects
ON khs.year=subjects.year, khs.program =subjects.program, khs.codemk = subjects.codemk;
```

But not sure if that is what you asked, otherwise:

```
SELECT khs.id khs.codemk, subjects.namemk, subjects.tm, subject.pr, subjects.lp
FROM khs 
RIGHT JOIN subjects
ON CONCAT(khs.year,khs.program, khs.codemk) = CONCAT(subjects.year, subjects.program, subjects.codemk);
```

Comment: Thank You guys, yes you all answer my question, it just me do not now how to combine field value (i am an old dbase programmer try to adapt with new mysql database) CONCAT is the answer for my question, but all the answer from others respectively answer my question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a join? Why not try something like this:

```
SELECT codemk,namemk,tm,pr,lp
FROM khs,subjects
WHERE khs.year = subjects.year
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your result expectetions (could you provide it please? as well as samples of data tables) but you can try for now:

```
SELECT khs.id khs.codemk, subjects.namemk, subjects.tm, subject.pr, subjects.lp
FROM khs 
INNER JOIN subjects
ON khs.year = subjects.year
 AND khs.program = subjects.program
 AND khs.codemk =  subjects.codemk;
```

Comment: You are my savior ! yes that is the answer of my problem, Thank You. Have A Nice Day